# Execution failed for task ':app:packageStageDebug'

Tags: android, unit-testing, jacoco

Execution failed for task ':app:packageStageDebug'.

> Several variant outputs are configured to use the same file name "resources-stageDebug.ap_", filters : MAIN:MAIN

Im getting this error, when I try running my JacocoTestReport, what are the possibilities that are leading to this error